# Como puedo compilar varios archivos typescript en un directorio

Tags: typescript

Tengo un proyecto cuya estructura de archivos y carpetas es la siguiente

```
app
core
|--Cumulus
|--|--Cumulu.ts
|--Dimensions
|--|--Dimension.ts
|--Galaxies
|--|--Galaxy.ts
|--SolarSystems
|--|--SolarSystem.ts
|--Universes
|--|--Universe.ts
c137.ts
package.json
```

Quisiera saber como puedo transcompilar todos los archivos `.ts` sin tener que pasar por cada uno `tsc file.ts`, `tsc file2.ts`, `tsc file3.ts`, lo esperado sería algo así:

```
app
core
|--Cumulus
|--|--Cumulu.js // javascript
|--|--Cumulu.ts
|--Dimensions
|--|--Universe.js // javascript
|--|--Universe.ts
|--Galaxies
|--|--Galaxy.js // javascript
|--|--Galaxy.ts
|--SolarSystems
|--|--SolarSystem.js // javascript
|--|--SolarSystem.ts
|--Universes
|--|--Universe.js // javascript
|--|--Universe.ts
c137.js // javascript
c137.ts
package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré realizar lo que quería creando un archivo `tsconfig.ts`, añadiendole esto y ejecutando `tsc` en la *consola*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "files": [
        "c137.ts" // Aquí añado un archivo estático también a compilar
    ],
    "include": [
        "core/**/*", // Con esta línea pude compilar todos los archivos ts dentro de las subcarpetas de core
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que buscas es compilar todos los archivos `.ts` de un proyecto (*o directorio*), solo necesitas hacer dos cosas:

1.- Crear un archivo [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) donde podrás establecer las opciones para el `compiler`. Abre una terminal, ubicate sobre el directorio raíz de tu proyecto y ejecuta:

```
$ tsc --init
# message TS6071: Successfully created a tsconfig.json file.
```

2.- Por último solo queda ejecutar el `compiler` sobre el directorio

```
$ tsc -p ./
```

Mas info: [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)